# Python regex word, ip and port combination match

Tags: python, regex, ip

I have a list of phrases from a log and I want to validate the names using following regex expression. `phrase` is a valid thing but I am still getting this failed. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this?

Thank You very much!

```
phrase = "ServerName.192.168.12.12.52915"
regex = re.compile("\bServerName\.\^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,5}$")

res = regex.match(phrase)
if test:
   print "pass"
else:
   print "fail"
```

Comment: You input has no carets, and your pattern has `\^`. Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7lW1/2). You do not even need any `\b` at the start of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you. It was an easy thing to miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `^` in your input, but you define it in the regex pattern. Remove it.
Also, since you are using `re.match` that anchors the search at the start of a string, you do not need the initial `\b`. And use a raw string literal for safety.

```
r"ServerName\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,5}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ7lW1/2).

Comment: Thank you . The regex demo is really useful when developing the pattern.